# How to trigger Workflow on item update SharePoint designer Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

I am trying to create List workflow. [image]

Once I have create new item then it worked. but I am looking for once we update item then need restart that workflow.

There is two values for Answered column "YES" and "NO". Initially Value set to "NO" that time my workflow Worked. but I am looking for Once we edit that value to "Yes" then it restart the Workflow.

Please let me know any solution to trigger workflow when item is updated.

Thanks,

Sachin Shinde

Comment: That's an out of the box option to start a workflow on item created and/or item modified. Is this a long running workflow that you want to force a restart of?

Answer (score 2):

In the workflow settings, in the start options, you could select the option “Start workflow automatically when an item is changed.”.

It will trigger workflow when the item is updated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working ...I have tried it already. there is any other way for doing it.    MY workflow started automatically when new item is created but it's not worked when item is updated.

Comment: The workflow is triggered when new item is created. Then check if the workflow is finished, if not, when you update the item, the workflow will not be triggered on the same item.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Reminder Workflow by using Sharepoint designer 2013]

I have created reminder workflow as below and it's working fine for me, also we can start workflow when item is created(Designer default settings) but in my case I have write javaScript to trigger workflow when item updated.